# Can't ping through default gateway

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, raspberry-pi

I have the following configuration:

[image: network-configuration]

Routing table on M3 is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Routing table on M1 is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
```

So basically M3's gateway is M1, and M1's gateway is M2's wireless internet interface.
If I ping **8.8.8.8** from M1, everything is ok, replies are received. Pinging from M1 to M3 and viceversa is also possible.

I have configured M1 as gateway trafic forwarder using ***firestarter*** package and stopped firewall with it.

iptables policies are **ACCEPT** for everything.

**Problem**: I have tried ping-ing ip **8.8.8.8** from M3 but without success.

What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: Could you pls post M1's routing table, and state whether you can ping M1 from M3?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae edited and added required information.

Comment: Is that a typo where M1 and M2 have the same IP on the 192.168.2.x network?  And which device has 192.168.0.1 - does it have a route for 192.168.2.x?

Comment: You should use tcpdump or wireshark on M1 to see where M3 pings disappear.

Comment: @Paul, no, it's actually a bridged connection between the virtual machine and my laptop and I've configured both interfaces with that IP. 192.168.2.101 should have a route through switch->m3(192.168.2.1)->m1->m3(192.168.0.101)->wireless(192.168.0.1)

Comment: Sure but does the wireless router know about 192.168.2.x?

Comment: Well .. it should, M1 is configured as gateway.

Answer (score 0):

From M1 you can ping outside, and from M3 you can ping M1. Thus the only mis-configuration may occur inside M1, as a go-between.

I am not familiar with the firestarter package, but in Debian I would have configured M1 as follows (commands to be issued as sudo):

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
 iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
 iptables --append FORWARD  --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

The first command generically allows forwarding. The other two instructions activate nat (the first one) and allow forwarding from M3. I suspect this may be the root of your problem because you stated that iptables has been disabled.

Comment: I should flush first right?

Comment: Ping still doesn't work with manual gateway configuration.